# cdk call CfnBucket (first level) from IBucket refernce

Tags: aws-cdk

my objective is to call a first level cdk command starting from an interface: IBucket.

I can get the bucket reference starting from this:

`const sourceBucket = props.glueTable.bucket;`

Afterwords, I need to call:

`cfnBucket.replicationConfiguration = {`

The procedure is exactly as for the script below:
https://github.com/rogerchi/cdk-s3-bucketreplication/blob/main/src/index.ts

But, as you can see, this script requires:

`readonly sourceBucket: s3.Bucket;`

Since it is needed to call:

`const sourceAccount = cdk.Stack.of(props.sourceBucket).account;`

Finally, are there really no other ways to call a cloudformation level 1 command starting from a reference?
It looks odd.

Thank you in advance
Marco

Comment: What do you want to do with the replication configuration property? Set us or get it? Also, `cdk.Stack.of(props.sourceBucket).account` can be done using any construct, L1 or L2 so it doens't make much sense to include it in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an example on exactly this in the aws docs:

If a Construct is missing a feature or you are trying to work around an issue, you can modify the CFN Resource that is encapsulated by the Construct.

All Constructs contain within them the corresponding CFN Resource. For example, the high-level Bucket construct wraps the low-level CfnBucket construct. Because the CfnBucket corresponds directly to the AWS CloudFormation resource, it exposes all features that are available through AWS CloudFormation.

The basic approach to get access to the CFN Resource class is to use construct.node.defaultChild (Python: default_child), cast it to the right type (if necessary), and modify its properties. Again, let's take the example of a Bucket.

```
// Get the CloudFormation resource
const cfnBucket = bucket.node.defaultChild;

// Change its properties
cfnBucket.analyticsConfiguration = [
  { 
    id: 'Config'
    // ...        
  } 
];
```

From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/cfn_layer.html

For you, it wouldn't be analyticsconfiguration but bucketreplication of course.